Why is looping with Array.concat giving me this result on Hackerrank?
I took a Hackerrank screening and ran into this issue with using Array.concat(). I was wondering what I'm missing?
The function was essentially:
async function getData(id) {
  let data = []
  let end = false
  let page = 1
  while (!end) {
    const result = await getSomeResult(id, page)
    data = data.concat(result['data'])
    if (result['page'] == result['total_pages']) {
        end = true
    }
    page++;
  }
  return data
}

The total length of data in the test case is supposed to be 67. When I ran the test case, the length was 7 - the page size is 10 so I'm thinking the final loop's data = data.concat(result['data']) is setting data to [].concat(~finalResultData~). When I added a ws.write to the loop, data was correct (67) before the return. Am I missing something with async await here?
getSomeResult performs a fetch() with id and page params. When I add console.log(data.length) inside the loop the output was:
10
20
30
40
50
60
67

but when I remove the log inside the loop and console.log before the return data, I get 7.

Is that not an infinite loop? You're always fetching the same data in a loop because id never changes.

Ah sorry, there was some pagination logic in there I forgot to include in the post

We also don't know what getSomeResult() does or what the response you're getting back from the API looks like.

Sidenote: Node (finally) added support for the Fetch API as of v19 so if you're on the current active LTS (v20) you don't need node-fetch anymore.

My best guess (not seeing the actual data) is that you're accidentally building an array of objects or an array of arrays based on a false assumption of what result['data'] contains.  If so, the 7 represents the seven fetches and not the 7 expected members of the last fetch.
